# Drop Shadow Center Column Website web page

Tags: html, css, dropshadow, shadows

How can I add a drop shadow effect to a website that has one center column?

Some examples of what I mean:

[lala.com](http://lala.com)
[mint.com](http://mint.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are both done with background images:

See Mint: http://www.mint.com/images/global/body.jpg
See LaLa: http://s.pplala.com/static/24.4.1-25/images/background.png

LaLa's is repeating, where Mint uses one large image.

Answer (score 0):

They've done it with a centered background-image on their body. The image has the shadow on it.

If you're ready to sacrifice a little beauty on older browsers, I would suggest you use [`-webkit-box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-box-shadow). Coding designs that degrade gracefully encourages people to use recent browsers for a better Web, while not making your website unusable for people who can't.